# strong law of large number

Tags: pr.probability

Let $\{c_n\}$ be a descending sequence of positive real numbers, and let $\{X_i\}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables.

Are the following statements equivalent?

1. $\operatorname{E}(X_1^2) < \infty$ and $\operatorname{E}(X_1) = 0$ implies $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} c_n \sum \limits_{i = 1}^n X_i \xrightarrow{a.s.} 0$.
2. $\sum \limits_{i = 1}^\infty c_i^2 < \infty$ .

Thank you for any replies or comments.

Comment: You probably want to look at the law of the iterated logarithm. A more or less correct condition on $c_n$ is $c_n\sqrt{n\log(\log n)}\to\infty$.

Comment: I meant $c_n\sqrt{n\log\log n}\to 0$ is sufficient by LIL.

Comment: see, for instance, Theorem 2.5.7, p. 71 of [this book](http://www.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/pte.html). you can adapt it to your $c_n$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Law of the Iterated Logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_iterated_logarithm) tells you 
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{S_n}{\sqrt {n\log\log n}}\right|=\sigma\sqrt 2\text{ with probability 1,}
$$
where $S_n:=X_1+\ldots+X_n$, and $\sigma^2=\mathbb EX_1^2$. Hence if 
$\sqrt{n\log\log n}\cdot c_n\to 0$, one has $c_nS_n\to 0$ with probability 1.

This is not quite a necessary and sufficient condition, because you can construct decreasing sequences $(c_n)$ that *most of the the time* are of smaller order than $1/\sqrt{n\log\log n}$, but occasionally are as big as $1/\sqrt{n\log\log n}$, for which $c_nS_n$ still goes to 0 almost surely, but if you want $c_n$ to be some kind of regularly decaying sequence, then this is exactly the right condition.

Comment: According to The Theorem 2.5.7, p. 71 of this book http://www.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/pte.html, and your accurate answer ,i think now that i'm understanding it well, thank you very much